# How can an SBT plugin depend on another plugin

Tags: sbt

I want to write a plugin "MyPlugin" that depends on the another plugin 
("io.spray" %% "sbt-twirl" % "0.6.0").

Simply adding sbt-twirl in libraryDependencies will not work,
because plugins get published with a different path scheme
than standard libraries.

I also cannot declare sbt-twirl as a plugin dependency to MyPlugin
project, because MyPlugin does not use the sbt-twirl directly,
it is the project using MyPlugin that will indirectly use it.

MyPlugin provides a task that is meant to be run after sbt-twirl
has generated it's sources (in sourceManaged) and after compilation.

A simple but non ideal solution would be to require the project using
MyPlugin to also declare sbt-twirl as a plugin dependency, but it is not
DRY because the two plugins will be sharing some settings (directories, versions, etc), 
and they will have to be repeated and compatible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It should be the same definition as for using a plugin as a plugin, except that it goes in `build.sbt` or `project/Build.scala` instead of `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-twirl" % "0.6.0")
```

Comment: I did : .settings(addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-twirl" % "0.6.0")), and it worked. Thanks

Comment: This was surprisingly difficult for me to find, but the solution was so simple!