# Inherit .sbt files

Tags: scala, sbt

I have many small Scala applications and I would like a central place to manage versions of common dependencies.

I know I can set up a Build.scala file and define multiple projects. I used to have that, but not all of these applications are related in that sense. They just happen to share a common software architecture.

How do I achieve this with SBT? Currently I'm managing multiple .sbt files that I batch update (like dependencies.sbt, common.sbt etc.).

My initial approach was to start writing a plugin, but I got stumped along the way with getting dependencies working within the plugin.

I wanted to collect plugin settings and build settings. But I never got one plugin to depend on a set of other plugins.

Anyone tried this before, how do I manage central application profiles (both plugins and settings)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean *different* applications? You can then just put your settings into `global.sbt`.  You can look for more detailed description [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Global-Settings)

Comment: Yes different applications with common basic design. What you're describing is not exactly what I'm looking for, but could be a fall back solution. I was hoping to add a dependency (plugin) that in turn contains common settings, dependencies and plugin configurations. I want to depend on these and have them available in my projects (in both plugin and build files). I would publish the plugin and just reference it from a project. But I get into a chicken and hen issue with how to get one plugin to depend on another plugin?

Comment: For a plugin depending on another plugin, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14441416/850196.